# perl file overwriting itself in loop

Tags: perl, file, for-loop, overwrite

So I have a loop where I am printing out values to a file. The only problem is, I only ever get the last print of the loop. For example, if this were what is being printed in my loop:

```
1 1
2 2 
3 3
```

All my file would have would be `3 3` as the first and only line. Here is my code:

```
open my $f, '>', 'file.txt';

#$node_id set above somewhere...
for my $key (keys %{$todo->{$node_id}->{'urls_hash'}}) { 
    print $f "$node_id $todo->{$node_id}->{'urls_hash'}->{$key}->{'domain_id'}\n";
}

close $f;
```

I've tried using `$| = 1` to flush, but that didin't seem to do anything. I was hoping maybe someone had run into this before. And sorry for the hash of hash of...etc. I know it's messy :)

Comment: can you also print your data on the standard output to see that it's really the file, not your data that is wrong?

Comment: yes, I've printed to STDOUT and I've gotten the output that I listed first.

Comment: have you tried using different file name?

Comment: You did not demonstrate your problem. Provide the input that causes that code to malfunction.

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich, I just did and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @ikegami, it's just values I pull out of a database put into a has of form $todo->{int}->{'key_that_gives_hash'}->{int}->{'domain_id'} and that yields an int.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that reading from a database would not be appropriate here. You are wrong that this matters. There are other ways of populating a data structure. Please do so. The code you provided is worthless without context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says `#$node_id set above somewhere...`. From your expected output:

```
1 1
2 2 
3 3
```

It's hard to say without the code which is setting `$node_id` but it looks like you're reopening the file each time you increment `$node_id`. Is there another loop you need to move the `open` outside?

Comment: Thank you. That was it. That loop was so far in another I didn't realize. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This not an anwer to your question, sorry.

To append a file use >> when open a file.

```
open my $f, '>>', 'file.txt';
```

Comment: But I'm not wanting to append to an existing file, I'm creating a file for the first time.